# Password failing for one webite on Imacros

Tags: passwords, imacros, recording

I am using imacros and Chrome to record logins to 5 websites. I use no encryption, and just type in my login and password for each site. Four of the sites work fine, but  www.sportsbetting.ag, gives me a webpage that says my "The Password field must have a value". When I walk through the steps I can see that for this site it puts in the correct login but a nonsensical password instead of the one I included in the code.

```
VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=https://www.sportsbetting.ag/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:loginForm ATTR=ID:CustomerID CONTENT=SB341413
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:loginForm ATTR=ID:Password CONTENT=FAKEword
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:loginForm ATTR=ID:button-submit-login
```

For privacy I have used FAKEword above instead of the actual password but I have checked the actual login and password many times to ensure I've typed it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In similar situations you can try to record your macros in **'Experimental event recording mode'**. Perhaps the following code may work:

```
VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=https://www.sportsbetting.ag/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:loginForm ATTR=ID:CustomerID CONTENT=SB341413

EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>HEADER>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>FORM>LABEL:nth-of-type(2)>INPUT" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>HEADER>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>FORM>LABEL:nth-of-type(2)>INPUT" CHARS="FAKEword"

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:loginForm ATTR=ID:button-submit-login
```